# Angular $sce.trustAsHtml on textarea with html identical to ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a textarea marked up and augmented with angular like the HTML below:

```
<textarea
  ng-model="message.reply"
  ng-bind-html="message.reply"
</textarea>
```

In my controller, I'm setting `$scope.message.reply` equal to a string with HTML on a response from an HTTP request.

In the success function on the HTTP request, I'm concatenating onto the `message.reply` string with HTML links.  However, in the textarea, these are appearing as text and not HTML.

In the success function my code looks something like this:

`$scope.message.reply += $sce.trustAsHtml('<a href="link1">' + res.data.file.link + '</a>');`

It's concatenating properly, but it's not trusting as HTML.  I have `ngSanitize` included in my project and it works elsewhere, but isn't working in this textarea.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A textarea can not render HTML inside.

Comment: Is this an HTML thing or Angular thing?

Comment: It is an HTML thing. And it's possible those editors use divs that are set to contenteditable

Comment: They don't.  Looking at a WYSIWYG right now that is a textarea.  Is there some workaround?

Comment: I'd love to see a picture of what you're saying is a textarea with HTML inside

Comment: Where is this editor? I'm interested in seeing what's really going on here

Comment: Did you see the picture?

Comment: Yes, but it's not a definitive picture. I can't see any styles, other DOM, etc. For example, seeing this, my first thought is the textarea allows input, but what is actually shown is not the textarea itself